# Генерация случайных анонимных (lambda) функций

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа, lambda, eval

Мне нужно сгенерировать список анонимных функций (`lambda`), каждая из которых будет выполнять какое-либо математическое действие непосредственно c x и случайным числом. Но по какой-то причине, каждый раз элементы списка редактируются. Код программы:

```
from random import choice, randint

random_choices = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

random_actions = [lambda x: eval(f'{x} {choice(random_choices)} {randint(1, 50)}') for _ in range(len(random_choices))]

for i in range(4):
    print(random_actions[i](5))

print('\n')

for i in range(4):
    print(random_actions[i](5))
```

Вывод:

```
15
90
0.7142857142857143
12


0.10638297872340426
15
32
0.22727272727272727
```

Как можете заметить, при исполнении двух одинаковых циклов получаются разные результаты, как мне сделать так чтобы такого не было?

Comment: Простите а что именно "редактируется"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При исполнении двух совершенно одинаковых циклов с одинаковым аргументом получаю разные результаты, отсюда сделал вывод что элементы списка каким-то образом редактируются

Comment: Конечно вы будете получать разные результаты, ведь каждый каждый раз используются случайное действие `choice(random_choices)` и случайное число `randint(1, 50)`. Вероятность, что что-то случайно окажется одинаковым, крайне мала

Comment: Человек не понимает что у него не список значений, а список lambda функций. Что тоже является объектом, а в список можно запихнуть любой объект.

Comment: По-моему автор хотел, чтобы случайные значения выбрались один раз в момент создания лямбд, но это так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему данные "редактируются"? Вы будете получать разные результаты, ведь каждый каждый вызов лямбда функции используется случайное действие `choice(random_choices)` и случайное число `randint(1, 50)`. Вероятность, что что-то случайно окажется одинаковым, крайне мала. (ответ **@andreymal**)

Могу предложить данное решение проблемы:

```py
from random import choice, randint

random_choices = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

commands = ["{0}" + f"{choice(random_choices)} {randint(1, 50)}" for _ in range(len(random_choices))]

random_actions = lambda x: [eval(command.format(x)) for command in commands]

for i in range(4):
    print(random_actions(5)[i])

print('\n')

for i in range(4):
    print(random_actions(5)[i])
```

Вывод:

```sh
120
215
5
15

120
215
5
15
```

Comment: Функция `random_actions` возвращает список результатов, полученных при различных действиях над x

Comment: Спасибо большое!)